# Eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix that every block is circulant

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, circulant-matrices

For a matrix like
\begin{bmatrix}
    A & B \\
    B & A \\
\end{bmatrix}
which A and B are block matrix and are circulant, is there any simple way to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors? To be clear, following matrix is an example of my described matrix.
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    2 & 1 & 4 & 3 \\
    3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
    4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix commutes with the matrices
$$P_2 = P \oplus P$$ and $$X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & I \\ I& 0\end{pmatrix}$$ 
where $P$ is the cyclic permutation matrix on one subblock. Moreover, also $P_2$ and $X$ commute. Thus the three matrices can be simultaneously diagonalized. The combined eigenspaces of $P_2$ and $X$ have the form
$$E_{\lambda,\pm}  = \mathop{\rm span}\begin{pmatrix}v_\lambda \\ \pm v_\lambda \end{pmatrix}$$
with the eigenvalues $\lambda_j =e^{2\pi i j/n}$ and $$v_\lambda =(1,\lambda, \lambda^2, ...)^t.$$

As the eigenspaces are 1 dimensional, the eigenvectors of your matrix are given by $$\begin{pmatrix}v_{\lambda_j} \\ \pm v_{\lambda_j} \end{pmatrix}$$ and the eigenvalues are easily found.

In particular, the unitary transformation $$U=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} U_\text{DFT} & U_\text{DFT} \\ U_\text{DFT} & -U_\text{DFT}\end{pmatrix}$$ with $U_\text{DFT}$ the discrete Fourier transform brings your matrix onto diagonal form.